# Adding a new item with $recource in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have created a simple app to store an event to my database. It is working fine but with a wordaround.

I use the following method:

```
controllers.controller('CalendarAddController', function($scope, $routeParams, Event) { 
    $scope.addEvent = function() {
        $scope.ev=new Event();
        $scope.ev.title = $scope.event.title;
        $scope.ev.$save().then(function(res)  { console.log("success");})
        .catch(function(req) { console.log("error saving obj"); })
        .finally(function()  { console.log("always called") });
    }
});
```

After submitting my form, the function addEvent is called.
If I print the value of $scope.event, it has the right values.
However, when I call .$save() on it, I get the error "TypeError: $scope.event.$save is not a function."

But when I create a new object and assign the values to it, it works fine.

Why isn't it working directly? Always creating a dummy object does not seem to be best practice I suppose.

The service I created

```
services.factory( 'Resource', [ '$resource', function( $resource ) {
    return function( url, params, methods ) {
      var defaults = {
        update: { method: 'put', isArray: false },
        create: { method: 'post' }
      };

     methods = angular.extend( defaults, methods );

     var resource = $resource( url, params, methods );

     resource.prototype.$save = function() {
       if ( !this.id ) {
         return this.$create();
       }
       else {
         return this.$update();
       }
     };

     return resource;
   };
 }]);

services.factory( 'Event', [ 'Resource', function( $resource ) {
   return $resource( '/api/calendar/:id' );
}]);
```

Update: basic example

Using this example everything works front-end but in my rest API the data is not passed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','ngResource'])
.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
                controller  : 'mainController'
            })
    });

app.factory('Event', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/test/api/:id');
});
app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Event',
    function($scope, $routeParams, Event) {
        function handleSuccess(data) {
            alert("success");           
        }
        function handleError(data) {
            alert("error");         
        }     
        var event = new Event();
        event.title = "a title";
        Event.save(event, handleSuccess, handleError);
}]);
</script>
<body>
    <div ng-app="app">
      <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

For the back-end I created a very basic script which writes the request to a file:
It always says "array()" so no data is passed.

```
<?php
    $myFile = "testFile.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    $stringData = print_r($_REQUEST,true);
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);
?>
```

Comment: could you put your Event service on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you initialize `$scope.event` or is it automatically created by angular? If this is an plain JavaScript object you can't call `.$save`, but you can use the Event service itself - no need to create a new instance:

```
Event.create($scope.event)
```

Comment: Ok I get that, however, I get an error: TypeError: Event.save(...).then is not a function

Comment: Usung your own Resource service you overwrite a few things. Check the available methods on `Event` - maybe you have to use `Event.create ($scope.event);`

Comment: It seems Event.save() does work, but ".then" is not working, probably because there is no promise returned. Is there a best practice to check the success or error result on Event.create(event) or Event.save(event) ?

Comment: I made a little [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pWc0Rv1RpfbMVJqEOh4K?p=preview) with your code. Of course I get an error back from the server, because POST request are not supported there, but you see that both methods `save` and `create` are working fine. The problem must be somewhere else. What error do you get back?

Comment: Thanks, I have made a very basic script which I have added in my original post. It seems it's working now, not getting any errors, but my data is not posted to the api.
Back-end I always receive an empty array.

Comment: I'm not ber familiar with PHP. But it think you need to read the request POST body differently See [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input)

Comment: Ok, no problem, you have solved my question so the PHP thing is another question/problem. Thx for your help, appreciate it.